# Suphp and mod_fcgid on one server

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-fcgid, suphp

Hi is it possible? My script not work with mod_fcgid, but work with suphp so I would like run one domain with suphp and other with mod_fcgid+xcache on one server. I don't want run every sites with suphp because xcache don't work with it.

Comment: I recently tried this by having `suPHP_Engine off` by default in the suphp.conf, and only turning it on in the `VirtualHost`s that needed it. However I then started having problems with sites which used fcgid, in that `.php` files would be served up as source code instead of being executed unless I completely disabled suPHP with `a2dismod`.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible look at this : http://brinet.net/enable-fastcgi-per-site

First configure your server to use suPHP using cpanel and enable mod_fcgid with easyphp

edit /usr/local/apache/conf/php.conf

add module and wrapper directive

```
# Fastcgi configuration for PHP5
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php
```

create/edit /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 containing

```
#!/bin/sh

# If you customize the contents of this wrapper script, place
# a copy at /var/cpanel/conf/apache/wrappers/php5
# so that it will be reinstalled when Apache is updated or the
# PHP handler configuration is changed

exec /usr/bin/php
```

make executable and owned by root
    chown root:wheel /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5
    chmod 755 /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5

Now add a handler in your .htaccess for .php and fcgid-script

restart apache

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: good point , will do